# Prove that $\{\sqrt[n]{e^{n+1}}\}$ is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, proof-verification, continuity

I need to prove that $\{\sqrt[n]{e^{n+1}}\}$ is convergent, and find its limit using this theorem:

Let $f:E \to R$ with $x_{0} \in E$ an accumulation point of $E$. Then these are equivalent:

1)$f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

2)$f$ has limit at $x_0$, and $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x)=f(x_0)$

3)For every sequence $\{x_n\}$ converging to $x_0$ with $x_n \in E$ for each n, $\{fx_n\}$ converges to $f(x_0)$

And assuming that $f(x)=e^{x}$ is continouos in all $R$
My attempt:

To see that $\{\sqrt[n]{e^{n+1}}\}$ converges we first note that each $a_n \in D_{e^{x}}=R$, Now we consider the sequence:

$f(x_n)= \{ e^{\sqrt[n]{e^{n+1}}\}} \}$ then we have that:

$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}e^{\sqrt[n]{e^{n+1}}\}}=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}e^{ee^{\frac{1}{n}}}=e^{e}=f(e) $

Thus   $\{\sqrt[n]{e^{n+1}}\}$ converges and converges to $e$.

Am I right? and How can I fix my mistakes? Thank you.

Comment: The sequence $$\frac{n+1}{n} = 1 + \frac{1}{n}$$ is convergent and $e^x$ is a continuous function.

Comment: Yes you are right :)

Comment: But I do not see how this help, Thank you :)

Comment: By (1), we use the fact that $e^x$ is continuous, by (2) You know for any $x_0$ we have $\lim e^x = e^{x_0}$, by (3) We use $\frac{n + 1}{n} \to 1$. What is $x_0$ and what is $x_n$?

Comment: $x_0$ is the accumulation point, and $x_n$ is an element of the sequence :)

Comment: Yes, but what sequence and what point am I talking about?

Comment: Well I do not know because they are arbitrary isnt it? I am a little confused with your comment :) thank you

Comment: $$1 + 1/1n = x_n$$, what is $x_0$?

Comment: 1 isnt it ?, jajajajaj Im still confused ?

Comment: Yes it is, so you are done.

Comment: Can you tell my why or how is that, is because I do not understand your idea, Thank you :) I am sorry